# java aplicar descuento

Tags: java

estoy con el siguiente ejercicio, y os pongo donde me he trabado, haber si me podéis echar un cable.

> Ejercicio 2
>
> Crea un proyecto Electrodomesticos, en él un paquete con el mismo
>   nombre y una clase Electrodomestico (en singular) que incluya

```
public class Electrodomestico {

    String numSerie;   

   String marca;

    double precio;

  //método (tipo get) que, aplicado sobre un objeto, accede al atributo numSerie del objeto y devuelve dicho atributo, es decir el número de serie

 String getNumSerie(){

return numSerie;

 }

//método (tipo set) que, aplicado sobre un objeto,  accede al atributo numSerie del objeto y lo modifica, cambiándolo por el que se ofrece como argumento (num)

 void setNumSerie(String num){

numSerie=num;

}  

/* el método anterior también se puede escribir     utilizando el operador this:

      void setNumSerie(String numSerie){

      this.numSerie=numSerie;

      }   */
```

1. Añade a la clase Electrodomestico los métodos que faltan para poder consultar y modificar el valor de todos los atributos.

   2. Elabora un método Constructor por defecto que inicialice los atributos a

      ```
      numSerie =”pendiente de asignar”

      marca="Balay"

      precio=120.99
      ```
   3. Elabora  un método Constructor con argumentos que se correspondan con los atributos de la clase.
   4. Crea los siguientes métodos:

Un método llamado **aplicar_Iva** que incrementa el precio en un 21%.
Otro método llamado **rebajar_precio**  que disminuye el precio en el porcentaje que pasamos como argumento, controlando en el propio método que el precio no llegue a ser menor de 10 euros, en ese caso le asignamos de precio 10.

Me he trabado en el punto de crear metodo rebajar_precio. Este es mi código:

```
public class Electrodomestico {

    String numSerie;   

    String marca;

    double precio;

  //método (tipo get) que, aplicado sobre un objeto, accede al atributo numSerie del objeto y devuelve dicho atributo, es decir el número de serie

    String getNumSerie(){

    return numSerie;

    }
    /* el método anterior también se puede escribir     utilizando el operador this:

      void setNumSerie(String numSerie){

      this.numSerie=numSerie;

      }   */

    void setNumSerie(String numSerie){

    this.numSerie=numSerie;

}  

    String getMarca(){

    return marca;

    }

    void setMarca(String marca){

    this.marca=marca;


}

    double getPrecio(){

    return precio;

    }

    void setPrecio(double precio){

    this.precio=precio;


}

Electrodomestico(){

    numSerie="Pendiente de asignar";
    marca="Balay";
    precio=120.99;
}

Electrodomestico(String numSerie,String marca, double precio){

    this.numSerie=numSerie;
    this.marca=marca;
    this.precio=precio;

}

public void aplicar_iva(){
this.precio= (21*precio/100);

}

public void rebajar_precio(double precio){

}

}
```

Comment: Pero si hiciste el de iva, porque te trabaste con este que es igual?!??!?!???? en donde tuviste problemas? o que probaste?

Comment: No entiendo que porcentaje es el que pasamos como argumento. Libre?

Comment: precio es tu porcentaje.. lo que pasa es que le pusiste mal el nombre...

Comment: Ahora si que me acabas de dejar loco. Explica con ejemplo por favor, no se por donde vas....

Comment: no puedo respondertelo, porque si no estaria haciendo tu ejercicio. Te estan pidiendo que hagas un calculo simple con el precio del item, y el porcentaje de descuento que te viene como parametro. y despues de eso, controles si es menor que 10. Si es menor, lo dejas en 10. prueba a hacer esa ecuacion, ponela en el ejemplo que subiste y seguimos...

Comment: Gracias, pero no puedo hacerlo, por que sigo sin entender lo que me explicas. Soy nuevo en java y entiendo que no me quieras hacer el ejercicio, aun que solo he pedido un ejemplo, aun que no sea el mismo. Pero tampoco sabes guiar a la persona por el camino que se debe de ir.

Comment: Si Ivan. Puedo guiarte. Sabes calcular matematicamente un porcentaje? bueno. si tenes un precio, y queres aplicar un descuento de un 10%, multiplicas el precio por 0.90. Si en tu funcion, viene el numero 10, entonces multiplicas precio por (100-porcentaje) y ya tienes tu nuevo precio. eso es solamente una operacion matematica. si pudiste escribir lo del iva, esto es lo mismo. Ahora, si no escribiste ni siquiera la funcion de IVA, entonces te recomendaria que empiezes por entender de donde copiaste ese codigo.

Comment: Y cuál es la duda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto un pseudocodigo que podría servirte:

```
RebajarPrecio (duoble porcentajeDescuento)
{
   precio = precio - (precio * porcentajeDescuento)
   Si (precio < 10){//Validas que el nuevo precio no sea menor a 10 euros
    precio=10
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Jaime, me ha servido para poder hacer el ejercicio